# Entab / Detab in VIM

Tags: vim, entab-detab

In normal text editors, you select the block of text and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to entab and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to detab.

How do I entab or detab a selected block of text in VIM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you select the text and hit ">" it will indent, and "<" will de-indent.

Whether it inserts tabs or spaces depends on your "expandtab" setting.  You can edit the number of spaces/tabstop with the "shiftwidth" and "tabstop" settings.

Comment: +1 Note: Shift V (Visual mode) to select the text block. Otherwise < and > will work on the current line.

Comment: You can also select a block of text and press = to get vim to auto-indent.

Comment: @MichaelM: Thanks for that tip! Post it as an answer please, instead of a comment. I'll upvote you

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Andy White's answer.
I would also add the following into vimrc:

```
vnoremap > >gv
vnoremap < <gv
```

So you wouldn't need to reselect your code block to indent/dedent further.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to select the text. You can indent/unindent the current line by hitting `>>` or `<<`.